# autocomplete extender or the combobox from the Ajax control toolkit

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

Earlier, when I had a question about *Depending source for drop down list*, somebody advised me this link: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/03/how-to-implement-auto-complete-textbox.html

But in this article does not have arrow bar and some things that work like drop down list when nothing typed in the text box.

i like some things that works like below picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. But this ain't jQuery

http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxCombo/index.shtml